# How to stop tagging me in group on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-tags

I know how to stop friends and strangers from tagging me in posts in my wall. But there seems to be no way that I can stop anyone in group when tagging me in posts in group. I don't find any personal settings for that in Facebook.

I'm annoyed with too many notifications. I see only unfollow option for the post. But still when you are tagged in post, you still get notifications.

I think I can remove tag and then unfollow. But every time I need to do that if anyone tags me.

Is there anyway I can stop people from tagging me in group?